# Python to Iterate first 50 element, run a test on that and iterate next 50 element and run a test on that till last 50 and print result

Tags: python

I am trying to test condition when iteration reach first 50 elements, then next 50 elements in a list based on certain conditions and so on. My list contains 630000 elements fed from df_. This is my attempt:

For a dataframe: df_

| distance |
| --- |
| 0.5 |
| 10.4 |
| 0.5 |
| 14.4 |
| 0.15 |
| 100.4 |
| 0.25 |
| 12.4 |

```
    mylist_data = list()
    mylist1_data = list()

    for index, row in df_.iterrows():
    mylist = (row.distance)
    mylist_data.append(mylist)
    mylist1 = (row.day_night)
    mylist1_data.append(mylist1)
    
    if (len(mylist_data)== 50):

        xmean = np.mean(mylist_data)

        ymean = np.mean(mylist1_data) 
         
             :
             :
                    
     print(index)
```

Thanks for your immense help!

Comment: Does your approach not work? Or are you just looking for a better solution

Comment: HI. It does not work. Because presently my first four lines after the "For" statement takes in all the elements of 630000. So when I put the condition  if (len(mylist_data)== 50): it simply skips it. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you saying these lines take in all the 630,000 rows? You are using .iterrows(), so `row` is only one row every iteration... Maybe you should indent your python code (you can use spaces)

Comment: I meant after the first 50 rows is calculated, and condition applied, it will not apply the condition any further cos the next count will be 51, 52 and so on. What i want is for the condition to be applied for consecutive 50 rows, like first 50 rows, 2nd 50 rows and so on. Thanks!

Comment: then just make lists empty again in your if-clause (at its end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```py
groups = df_.groupby(pd.cut(df_.index, int(630_000 / 50)))

for interval, sub_df in groups:
    xmean = sub_df['distance'].mean()
    ymean = sub_df['day_night'].mean()
    print(f'doing my test for indices {sub_df.index[0]} : {sub_df.index[-1]}')
```

Here - for each group you have the sub-dataframe! (and you don't have to iterate through rows, which is very inefficient).

[`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) returns a "categorical array-like object representing the respective bin" for each row of `df_`. It takes the number of bins as an argument: `int(630_000 / 50)`.